# How to exclude newline mark from requests.get().text

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-requests, newline

I'm trying to get rid of numbers from site response http://app.lotto.pl/wyniki/?type=dl with code below

```
import requests
import re

url = 'http://app.lotto.pl/wyniki/?type=dl'
p = re.compile(r'[^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}]\d+')

response = requests.get(url)
data = re.findall(p, response.text)
print(data)
```

but instead of `['7', '46', '8', '43', '9', '47']` I'm getting `['\n7', '\n46', '\n8', '\n43', '\n9', '\n47']` How can I get rid of `"\n"`?

Comment: You put a *sequence* into a *character class*, which means you are not sure what the pattern you wrote means. What was your intent?

Comment: `data = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(p, response.text)]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wanted to get only numbers form site but plain response looks like this:     2016-03-29
7
46
8
43
9
47

Comment: Come on, why didn't you just use [`re.findall(r'(?<!-)\b\d+\b(?!-)', response.text)`](https://ideone.com/Tx7S0C)? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB4uM4/1).

Comment: Thank you. I'm only amator so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is not appropriate because `[^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}]\d+`  matches any character but a digit, `{`, `4`, `}`, `-`, `2` and then 1 or more digits. In other words, you turned a *sequence* into a *character set*. And that *negated character class* can match a newline. It can match any letter, too. And a lot more. **`strip` will not help in other contexts, you need to fix the regular expression.**

Use

```
r'(?<!-)\b\d+\b(?!-)'
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/pB4uM4/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Tx7S0C)

This pattern will match 1+ digits (`\d+`) that are not preceded with a hyphen (`(?<!-)`) or any word characters (`\b`) and is not followed with a word character (`\b`) or a hyphen (`-`).

You code will look like:

```
import requests
import re

url = 'http://app.lotto.pl/wyniki/?type=dl'
p = re.compile(r'(?<!-)\b\d+\b(?!-)')

response = requests.get(url)
data = p.findall(response.text)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. In fact after changing regex I don't have to use `strip`

Answer (score 2):

You can strip `\n` using `strip()` function

```
data = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(p, response.text)]
```

I am assuming that `\n` can be in beginning as well as in end

Comment: It will only work with the current input. If the numbers appear in a slightly different context, the issue will remain. The problem is in the regular expression.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't read the regex. Thought it was simpler problem. My bad. +1 for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Since your numbers are strings, you can easily use `lstrip()` method for strings. Such method will indeed remove newline/carriage return characters at the left side of your string (that's why *l*strip).
You can try something like

```
print([item.lstrip() for item in data])
```

to remove your newlines.

Or you can as well overwrite `data` with the stripped version of itself:

```
data=[item.lstrip() for item in data]
```

and then simply `print(data)`.